# How to apply case after outer join in pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I am doing left outer join between two dataframes DF1 and DF2 . What I want to achieve is to copy the data from left dataframe to right one after left outer join .

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

# Create a Spark session
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("InnerJoinExample").getOrCreate()

# Create the first dataframe
df1 = spark.createDataFrame([("A", 1,122,'ret'), ("B", 2,122,'manu'), ("C", 3,122,'Ser')], ["letter", "number","rev","ind"])

# Create the second dataframe
df2 = spark.createDataFrame([("A", 4,122,'ret'), ("B", 5,122,'manu'), ("D", 6,122,'Ser')], ["letter", "value","rev_hh","ind_hh"])


leftouter_join = df1.join(df2, df1['letter'] == df2['letter'], "leftouter")

# Show the result of the join
leftouter_join.show()
```

Output is coming as

```
+------+------+---+----+------+-----+------+------+
|letter|number|rev| ind|letter|value|rev_hh|ind_hh|
+------+------+---+----+------+-----+------+------+
|     B|     2|122|manu|     B|    5|   122|  manu|
|     C|     3|122| Ser|  null| null|  null|  null|
|     A|     1|122| ret|     A|    4|   122|   ret|
+------+------+---+----+------+-----+------+------+
```

Required output :
For letter  c in DF1 there is no matching data in DF2, so DF1 data should get copied .

```
+------+------+---+----+------+-----+------+------+
|letter|number|rev| ind|letter|value|rev_hh|ind_hh|
+------+------+---+----+------+-----+------+------+
|     B|     2|122|manu|     B|    5|   122|  manu|
|     C|     3|122| Ser|  null| null| 122 |  Ser |
|     A|     1|122| ret|     A|    4|   122|   ret|
+------+------+---+----+------+-----+------+------+
```

This is small example . IN real I have 20 such columns which needs to be copied .

Comment: see `coalesce()` function. use it to replace nulls with value of the same row from another column.